# in pickadate.js `min` is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I have put a date picker for start date and end date.end end-date date picker I want to disable dates before start date.Your any help will be appreciated. Here is the code.

```
// Pikadate datepicker
    $('.datepicker').pickadate({
      selectMonths: true, // Creates a dropdown to control month
      selectYears: 15, // Creates a dropdown of 15 years to control year
      format: "mmm dd, yyyy" // Generic date format as per US standard
    });
    // Pikadate datepicker $('.datepicker').pickadate({
    $('#start_date').pickadate({
      selectMonths: true, // Creates a dropdown to control month
      selectYears: 15, // Creates a dropdown of 15 years to control year
      format: "mmm dd, yyyy", // Generic date format as per US standard
    });
    $('#end_date').pickadate({
      selectMonths: true, // Creates a dropdown to control month
      selectYears: 15, // Creates a dropdown of 15 years to control year
      format: "mmm dd, yyyy", // Generic date format as per US standard
      min: new Date($('#start_date').val()),
    });
```

here `min` in end date not working.

Comment: Did you check what is `new Date($('#start_date').val())`, probably _Invalid Date_

Comment: i check console.log($('#start_date).value())..its comming...i dont know how to check new Date($('#start_date').val())..

Comment: copy paste this in your console: `console.log(new Date($('#start_date').val()))`

Comment: Thu Jul 21 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)      is comming

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nicolapeluchetti/dAyzq/1/